# how to use sql statement to process this data?

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization

I have the following data that needs to be analyzed, and I can process the data through the code to become the result I need. But I would like to know if I can use SQL to process the results I need.

data

```
| id  | phoneNum    | callType | created          |
| --- | ----------- | -------- | ---------------- |
| 1   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-07 01:02 |
| 2   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-07 02:03 |
| 3   | 15000000000 | 2        | 2019-08-07 04:05 |
| 4   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-07 05:07 |
| 5   | 15000000000 | 2        | 2019-08-07 06:07 |
| 6   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-07 06:20 |
| 7   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-07 06:30 |
| 8   | 15000000001 | 1        | 2019-08-07 07:07 |
| 9   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-07 08:07 |
| 10  | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 08:07 |
```

to be

```
| phoneNum       | callType | created          | count |
| -------------- | -------- | ---------------- | ----- |
| 15000000000    | 1        | 2019-08-07 02:03 | 2     |
| 15000000000    | 2        | 2019-08-07 04:05 | 1     |
| 15000000000    | 1        | 2019-08-07 05:07 | 1     |
| 15000000000    | 2        | 2019-08-07 06:07 | 1     |
| 15000000000    | 1        | 2019-08-07 06:30 | 2     |
| 15000000001    | 1        | 2019-08-07 07:07 | 1     |
| 15000000000    | 1        | 2019-08-07 08:07 | 1     |
| 15000000000    | 1        | 2019-08-08 08:07 | 1     |
```

---

Add a use occasion:
Imagine that when a mobile phone calls, the last call is finally inserted into the database. This is the data source for data. However, when displaying this data, the data of the last call should be displayed on the first line. At this time, the fourth row in the database is compared with the third row. Since the types of incoming calls are different, this time should be independent of one line; if they are the same, they are not processed, and the original data is incremented by one count.

Comment: Please explain a bit how phonenum becomes `15000000000(2)`  on row 3?

Comment: What criterion are you grouping by?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Thank you for your reply. 15000000000(2) represents that the first two data are duplicated, grouped according to the callType.

Comment: Then why 1st and 3rd rows are not grouped together and it must be 3 then?

Comment: @IronFlare Thank you for your reply. This grouping is a bit like the call history on your phone. Do you know that?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No...This final result is similar to the call history on the phone.

Comment: @orangeChu I don't know about that application, specifically, but I will admit it seems a bit odd. Why are rows 1, 2, *and* 4 not grouped? Also, what determines the `created` timestamp of the merged rows?

Comment: please explain how you want to process the data. Not tech wise, business wise. Are you counting calls with calltype 1? Are you eliminating calls with the same calltype and created timestamp? Be specific on what logic will produce the result you want. If you dont know what you want to do, you will never find the way to do it

Comment: @IronFlare The row 1, 2, and 4 are not merged because their callTypes are different.

Comment: @orangeChu But they're not. All of them have a `callType` of `1`.

Comment: @Bonzay Imagine that when a mobile phone calls, the last call is finally inserted into the database. This is the data source for data. However, when displaying this data, the data of the last call should be displayed on the first line. At this time, the fourth row in the database is compared with the third row. Since the types of incoming calls are different, this time should be independent of one line; if they are the same, they are not processed, and the original data is incremented by one count.

Comment: @IronFlare I would like to add some occasions. Maybe I am not particularly perfect. Would you mind checking it out?

Comment: @orangeChu I still don't understand what you're trying to do, since the rules you've described *would* include rows 1, 2, and 4. If you mean that you want to add conditions your grouping, please include all relevant columns that you intend to use for these conditions.

Comment: @IronFlare I'm sorry about that. I've revised the theme. You can check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can handle this with a difference of `row_number()`:

```
select phonenum, count(*) as cnt, type, max(created)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by phonenum order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by phonenum, type order by id) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t
group by phonenum, type, (seqnum - seqnum_t);
```

Note:  This puts the count in a separate column (which makes more sense to me) rather than concatenating it on the phone number.

Let me show what happens by example:

```
  id  | phoneNum    | callType | created          | seqnum | seqnum_t
| --- | ----------- | -------- | ---------------- |--------|---------
| 1   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 01:02 |   1    |    1
| 2   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 02:03 |   2    |    2
| 3   | 15000000000 | 2        | 2019-08-08 04:05 |   3    |    1
| 4   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 06:07 |   4    |    1
```

Now the difference:

```
| id  | phoneNum    | callType | created          | seqnum | seqnum_t |
| --- | ----------- | -------- | ---------------- |--------|----------|
| 1   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 01:02 |   1    |    1     | 0
| 2   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 02:03 |   2    |    2     | 0
| 3   | 15000000000 | 2        | 2019-08-08 04:05 |   3    |    1     | 2
| 4   | 15000000000 | 1        | 2019-08-08 06:07 |   4    |    1     | 3
```

The difference matches the groups you want to find.  This is usually a sufficient illustration.  It can be proven that the difference does identify the groups.

EDIT:

Your revised problem may more easily be handled with `lag()` and cumulative sums:

```
select phonenum, count(*) as cnt, type, max(created)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_phonenum = phonenum and prev_type = type then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
             row_number() over (partition by phonenum, type order by id) as seqnum_t
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(type) over (order by id) as prev_type,
                   lag(phonenum) over (order by id) as prev_phonenum
            from t
           )
     ) t
group by phonenum, type, grp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This seems feasible! Would you mind explaining a little help for me?

Comment: Hi there. I found that I didn't list all the situations accurately, which led to your method failing to get the desired results in some cases. I've updated the theme. Can you help me to look at it again?

Comment: @orangeChu . . . I think the revised solution should work.

Comment: Thanks. Emmmm...the ninth and tenth lines are the same as phoneNum, but they should not be grouped together due to the difference in created. I found that your approach divides it into a group.

Comment: @orangeChu . . . That is not explained in your question.

Comment: My fault. I updated the expected results again. Can you check it again?

Comment: Depending on your approach, I added created (lag (date (created)) over (order by Id) as prev_created) grouping seems able to get the expected results. :)